# How to get Data Properties in Sparql

Tags: sparql, owl

i've this piece of ontology:

```
<NamedIndividual rdf:about="&titan;BE_Digit_Photo_Srl">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&v1;BusinessEntity"/>
        <Process:name>Digit Photo Srl</Process:name>
        <v1:category>E-Commerce</v1:category>
        <schema:description>a simple description</schema:description>
        <v1:offers rdf:resource="&titan;Offer_DigitFoto_Nikon_Coolpix_P520_1"/>
</NamedIndividual>
```

Now how can I get Process:name, v1:category and schema:description of a given BE_Digit_Photo_Srl individual via SPARQL query?

I'm a newbie with SPARQL and ontologies, so please help me.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I've solved in this way:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
PREFIX v1: <http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/consumerelectronics/v1#>
PREFIX process: <http://localhost:8080/OntologyRepository/Process.owl#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT ?name ?desc ?cat ?offers
 WHERE { ?individual  process:name  ?name .
 ?individual  schema:description  ?desc .
 ?individual  gr:category  ?cat. 
 ?individual gr:offers ?offers.
 FILTER regex(str(?individual), 'BE_Digit_Photo_Srl', 'i') }
```

I hope it helps another user :)

Comment: It's easier if show a query you have tried (together with complete data).

Comment: i've posted the solution editing my first post, thanks :)

Comment: @TinezRidan thanks for providing a solution. You can actually answer your own question - posting the solution *as an answer* (instead of adding it into your question). That way, it's more obvious this question was answered, which will help other user find this question (and the answer) more easily. Thanks!

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Sorry, i'm new in the forum and I don't know the rules :)

Comment: You can earn a badge by reading the entire [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page (which would give you a nice impression of the Q&A site too) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved in this way:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
PREFIX v1: <http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/consumerelectronics/v1#>
PREFIX process: <http://localhost:8080/OntologyRepository/Process.owl#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT ?name ?desc ?cat ?offers
 WHERE { ?individual  process:name  ?name .
 ?individual  schema:description  ?desc .
 ?individual  gr:category  ?cat. 
 ?individual gr:offers ?offers.
 FILTER regex(str(?individual), 'BE_Digit_Photo_Srl', 'i') }
```